# What is the easiest way to check just one *.c file from Linux kernel using pvs-studio?

Tags: pvs-studio

What is the easiest way to check just one *.c file from Linux kernel using pvs-studio?
Kernel is a huge project, maybe there is a way to avoid compilation of all files.

Answer (score 1):

If you have compilation parameters of the file in question, you could directly launch the analyzer on this file. [Here](https://www.viva64.com/en/m/0006/) is an example, and although it's for Windows version (i.e. PVS-Studio.exe), you could do the same under Linux, just replace 'PVS-Studio.exe' with 'PVS-Studio'.